# MVC unit testing a RedirectToAction that returns with a status code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to write a unit test for a controller that returns a `RedirectToAction` with the view, the controller, and also a status code. The return is below

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Errors", new {statusCode = StatusCodes.Status505HttpVersionNotsupported});
```

I have found several stack overflow articles but none of them helped me figure out what the problem is my unit tests look like.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_OnError_ThrowsException()
{
    //Arrange
    Service.Setup(m => m.GetAllViewModels()).Throws(new NullReferenceException());

    //Act
    var result = (RedirectToRouteResult) controller.Index();


    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Error", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
}
```

I keep get an exception thrown that says it can't cast

> RedirectToRouteResult to type RedirectToRouteResult

And I can't figure out another way to run this unit test so I can test my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after a few hours of frustration trying to figure out why the answers I found off stack overflow weren't working.

The problem was with all the answers I found was they wanted you to cast the `RedirectToAction` to `RedirectToRouteResult` if you do this you will run into an exception that gets thrown because it can't cast the `RedirectToAction` that we are using to `RedirectToRouteResult` the exception you get is

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult'.'

To fix this issue so you can unit test the controller, all you need to do is cast your controller call to `RedirectToActionResult` and then do the asserts so they look like `Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["valueName"]);`. The full code block looks like.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_OnError_RedirectsToErrorPage()
{
    //Arrange
    Service.Setup(m => m.GetAllViewModels()).Throws(new NullReferenceException());

    //Act
    var result = (RedirectToActionResult)controller.Index();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ActionName);
    Assert.AreEqual("Errors", result.ControllerName);
}
```

Comment: `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult'.'` You may wish to update the question to reflect that.